# JTree. Wrong gui update order

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtree

I have JTree. Child nodes are loaded dynamically when the parent node is expanded (treeExpanded event). Their loading time is a few seconds. I want to display the message "Wait" in the JLabel before starting this process. But it is displayed only after the end of the process. What's my mistake?

```
class TFrame extends JFrame  {
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode root;
    private DefaultTreeModel model;
    private JLabel label;
    TFrame(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300,300);
        JPanel lPanel=new JPanel();
        label=new JLabel();
        lPanel.add(label);
        add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,lPanel);
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        root=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
        model=new DefaultTreeModel(root,true);
        JTree tree=new JTree(model);
        tree.addTreeExpansionListener(new TreeExpansionListener() {
            @Override
            public void treeExpanded(TreeExpansionEvent event) {
                label.setText("Wait");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                model.insertNodeInto(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Node1"),root,0);
                model.insertNodeInto(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Node2"),root,1);
            }
            @Override
            public void treeCollapsed(TreeExpansionEvent event) {
            }
        });
        panel.add(tree);
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) section.

Comment: You’re blocking the Event Dispatching thread (with Thread.sleep) - you should use a SwingWorker to perform the background loading

Comment: See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details